# Trouble calculating cumulative sum of products

Tags: c++, increment

I have to make a program that calculates the population of the country each year .
in 2014 the populatin is x and in 2015 is x*(12%)  and each year is incremented by 12%.
I've tryed to do this way but couldn't get through it:

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;
int main(){
int year;
double pop=344000

  cout<<"Year of population: ";
cin >> year;

switch(year){
case 2014: cout<< "344000\n";
break;
case 2015: cout<< pop+=* 0.12 + pop ; //last year pop *0.12+ last year pop
break;
cout <<year;


}
system("pause");
return year;

}
```

I know its a mess but i really I'm noob in c++

Comment: What is this: `year+=* 0.12` ?

Comment: Fix your title please

Comment: you only need `year += (year*0.12)`

Comment: alternatively, year*1.12

Comment: This is so wrong.First, you don't have a variable where you store the population.Second, in the `case 2015` you want to multiply with the last year's population, not with the YEAR ITSELF (also this `year+=* 0.12 + year` is wrong, very wrong )

Comment: if you want to compute population for year x, where x > 2014, you should read the year as an integer, computing how many year passed from the key year for which you know the population, and the do the maths. There should be no switch at all...

Comment: i'm sorry your are right i redited the topic ..sorry

Answer (score 0):

increment next year`s population by 12 percent of last one , we check how many years is passed and increase the population with that **no need** for **switch**

```
   int main(){
    int year;
    int baseYear=2014;
    int dif;
    int population=2000; //number of people in 2014

       cout<<"Year of population: ";
       cin >> year;
       dif=year-baseYear
       for(int i=0;i<dif;i++)
         population+= ((0.12)*population) 
        cout << population;


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope looking at this code will help you to understand what you are missing.

```
include<iostream.h>
void main()
{
  int population= 3000000;
  int year;
  cout<<"Enter a year greater than or equal to 2014 ";
  cin>>year;

  if(year<2014)
    cout<<"year must be greater than or equal to 2014";
  elseif(year==2014)
    cout<<population;
  else
   {
     int i=2014;
     while(i<=year)
     {
       population=population*1.12;  
       i++;
     }
     cout<<"population";
   }
}
```